# Declaring methods in Model when using MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am a bit new to the MVC framework and need to know what is the best practice when working with one.

I have a model class called NewsFeed that contains field like news_title, news_publish_date, news_url.

```
class NewsFeed < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :feed_id, :link, :publish_date, :title

  def save_news_info(feed_id, news_title, news_link, news_publish_date, news_description)
    self.feed_id = feed_id
    self.title = news_title
    self.link = news_link
    self.publish_date = news_publish_date
    self.description = news_description
  end
end
```

The task is to read an rss feed and gather all the news it contains, so i made a class called FeedReader and in that class I am using a gem feedzirra to parse the feed link

```
class FeedReader

  attr_accessor :title, :url, :publish_date, :news_array

  def initialize(feed_url)
    @url=feed_url
  end

  def read
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(@url)
    @title = feed.title
    @url = feed.feed_url
    @publish_date = feed.last_modified
  end
end
```

My question is if this is a good practice to have a seperate class just like the model(NewsFeed) class and have a read function there, or should I declare the read function in my model class and delete FeedReader? (cauze I have been reading that putting too much functionality in model classes is frowned upon!!) and in future all the functionality (like sanitize news description, strip particular tags etc) gets coded in the model class which in turn grows bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should stay in `FeedReader`, but you might benefit from passing the `NewsFeed` instance (or a collection, which can handle a list of `NewsFeed` instances) to the method which extracts information from the feed (I am not sure if name `read` is so good in this context).

You mist keep in mind that there are both Atom and RSS feeds. And you should not weld your code to one of the formats. Instead you should be able to work with both (if required) by utilizing polymorphism.

As for SRP: actually the best explanation for it , that i have heard is following - *class should have only one reason to change*.

Comment: Thanks! so if at some point I change my DB schema which in turn will require me to change the feedreader class too, this wont be considered as a bad design?

Comment: Only if your reader accesses variables of `NewsFeed` directly (and that would mean breaking the encapsulation).

Answer (score 2):

There's several opinion around that. Here's mine : you're doing the right thing. There's a thing called "principle of simple responsability", which is kind of a buzz word these days, but still has value : your objects should do one "thing", and do it well. So, having one class for handling the news feeds, and one that handles the retrieval of news, it makes complete sense to me.

Bonus point : it is (supposedly) easier to test.